# Android Studio 3.2 does not aware of Jetifier

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewpager, androidx

Here is a little piece of code in an Android app, after "Migrate to AndroidX..." on Android Studio 3.2.

`fun configureViewPager(
    pageIndicator: PageIndicator, 
    pager: androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPaager) {
    ...
    pageIndicator.setViewPager(pager)
    ...
}`

Variable `pageIndicator` is a reference of PageIndicator of https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator. It has a method `setViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager view)` to connect the object to a viewPager in layout.

On the other hand, variable `pager` is a view pager of AndroidX. So it is obvious that there is a mismatch by passing an AndroidX's `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPaager` to a method of `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.

However Jetifier of Android SDK can detect that and transform the `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPaager` reference to `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` in the library at build time, so it compile successfully.

The problem is, the line of code above still trigger an error in Android Studio code editor, and a read underline is shown. Is it a bug (or lack of feature) that Android Studio does not aware what Jetifier is going to do? Or there are some setting to make it aware of that?

In the mean time, I make the problem a little more tolerable by creating a Kotlin
extension function:

`fun PageIndicator.setViewPagerX(pager: ViewPager /* AndroidX's */) {
    setViewPager(pager)
}`

Then the line of code mentioned above is changed to

`pageIndicator.setViewPagerX(pager)`

so that the same error all over the code base occurs once only.

Any idea to make it better?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled Jetifier and it doesn't seem to do anything,
try deleting `.idea/libraries` directory and then do a gradle sync.
`File -> Sync Project with Gradle files`

It seems that if Jetifier is enabled after Android Studio has already downloaded some dependencies,
it won't properly detect and convert legacy dependencies.